# Cannot set pixel width of div using css width attibute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a div which contains 4 divs. I want to set the width of the container and some of the contained divs to set values but they just seem to take the width of the content.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
div {
    border: 1px solid #888;
}

.container {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.container div {
    display: inline;
    }

.div1 {
    width: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.div2 {
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.div3 {
    width: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.div4 {
    width: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    right: 0px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="div1"><img src="1x1.gif" width="1" height="1"/></div>
    <div class="div2"><span>date</span></div>
    <div class="div3"><span>text</span></div>
    <div class="div4"><span>twistie</span></div>    
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

The result looks like this:

```
+--+----+----+------------------------+---+
|  |date|text|                        |twi|
+--+----+----+------------------------+---+
```

Can anyone explain why the left-hand divs are not being set to the required widths?

Comment: Are these meant to be column headers? It seems like a table might be more appropriate.

Comment: Not column headers. Don't want to use a table as the styles *might* change significantly...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i think it's because of display:inline style
try this:

```
<div style='width:100px;overflow:hidden;'>
 <div style='float:left;width:20px'></div>
 <div style='float:left;width:20px'></div> 
 <div style='float:left;width:20px'></div>
 <div style='clear:both;'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inline elements do not use any width or height you specify.

Answer (score 21):

The reason you can't set the widths is because you are setting `display:inline;`.

When elements are displayed inline, they cannot have their dimensions specified because the size of the element is determined by the length of the text within it.

By default, `<div>` tags are set to `display:block;`. This mode can have its height and width specified, but defaults to being displayed below the preceding block.

There are two ways around this for you:

- Use `display:block;` and `float:left;`  --  This will change the blocks into floating elements, which means that subsequent elements will wrap around them. When used with other blocks, this effectively allows you to line them up. However using `float` can have other unexpected side-effects, due to the wrap-around effect I described.
- Use `display:inline-block;`  --  This is my preferred solution to this question. `inline-block` is a half-way house mode between `block` and `inline`. It allows an element to be treated as inline for the purposes of document flow, but still behave like a block internally, in that it will always be rectanguar and you are able to specify height and width, etc. It does have a few quirks (most notably poor support in IE6), but in general for what you're trying to achieve, it's a much cleaner solution and doesn't have the odd side-effects of `float`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Change your CSS as follows

```
.container div {
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

When you set the container div to inline, you actively set all of its children to inline as well, you may as well have just been using `<span>`s.

Here is an example for you to see.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/ZwKDb/

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.container div {
  float: left;
}
```

Should do the trick. Remove the inline display on the interior divs, and float all the divs left. Then you can specify the widths of the divs and any margins between them.